# JavaScript Function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function from an external javascript file when I click a button from a navigation bar. The various buttons on my navigation bar have been each assigned IDs as the ID is the parameter for my function eg:

```
<li><a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Weight Machines</a>
  <ul class="dropdown" aria-label="submenu">
    <li><button id="c" onclick="addObject(this.id)">Leg Extension</button></li>
    <li><button id="d" onclick="addObject(this.id)">Hamstring Curl</button></li>
    <li><button id="e" onclick="addObject(this.id)">Cable Machine</button></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I'm initially just testing this with an alert box [although really I'm trying to add an object into my three.js scene so things like scale will be affected by my choice upon adding]:

```
function addObject(clicked_id) {

  alert(clicked_id);}
```

This function works perfectly when the js with a script that is not of type="module", however I have several import statements in my script and they cant be imported when the script is not of type module. So when I click a button I get the following message :

```
addObject() is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I tried putting the imported js files into the HTML instead of my main script but that gives a reference error even though the source is not missing:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DragControls is not defined
```

If anyone would have an alternative solution to this I would be very greatful!

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to bind `onclick` via HTML, try to add the click event listeners solely in JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```html
<li><a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Weight Machines</a>
  <ul class="dropdown" aria-label="submenu">
    <li><button id="c">Leg Extension</button></li>
    <li><button id="d">Hamstring Curl</button></li>
    <li><button id="e">Cable Machine</button></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
// First, get the buttons
var buttonC = document.getElementById("c");
var buttonD = document.getElementById("d");
var buttonE = document.getElementById("e");

// Second, assign click event
buttonC.addEventListener("click", addObject, false);
buttonD.addEventListener("click", addObject, false);
buttonE.addEventListener("click", addObject, false);

// Then add event listener
function addObject(event) {
    let targetID = event.target.id;

    // use targetID as you please
}
```